# POST with bodies larger than 64k to Express.js failing to process

Tags: express, http, fetch, body-parser

I'm attempting to post some json to an express.js endpoint.  If the size of the json is less than 64k, then it succeeds just fine.  If it exceeds 64k, the request is never completely received by the server.  The problem only occurs when running express directly locally. When running on heroku, the request proceeds without issue.

The problem is seen across MacOS, Linux (ubuntu 19), and Windows.  It is present when using Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.

When I make requests using `postman`, the request fails.

If I make the request using `curl`, the request succeeds.

If I make the request after artificially throttling chrome to "slow 3G" levels in network settings, the request succeeds.

I've traced through express and discovered that the problem appears when attempting to parse the body.  The request gets passed to `body-parser.json()` which in turns called `getRawBody` to get the Buffer from the request.

`getRawBody` is processing the incoming request stream and converting it into a buffer.  It receives the first chunk of the request just fine, but never receives the second chunk.  Eventually the request continues parsing with an empty buffer.

The size limit on bodyparser is set to `100mb`, so it is not the problem.  `getRawBody` never returns, so body-parser never gets a crack at it.

If I'm logging the events from `getRawBody` I can see the first chunk come in, but no other events are fired.

Watching wireshark logs, all the data is getting sent over the wire.  But it looks like for some reason, express is not receiving all the chunks.  I think it's got to be due to how express is processing the packets, have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the off chance anyone in the future is running into the same thing:  The root problem in this case was that we were overwriting `req.socket` with our `socket.io` client.  `req.socket` is used by node internally to transfer data.  We were overwriting such that the first packets would get through, but not subsequent packets.  So if the request was processed sufficiently quickly, all was well.

tl;dr: Don't overwrite `req.socket`.